# Why is reading properties of null undefined sometimes but other times throws an error?

Tags: javascript, null

Example 1: When `res` is `null`, `coords` is `undefined`.

```
const res = await Geolocation.getGeolocation();
const { coords } = res || {};
```

Example 2: When `res` is `null`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'points')`

```
const res = await API.getPoints(
          latitude,
          longitude,
          market,
        );
const { points } = res;
```

Example 2 comes right after Example 1 in my code, why would the behavior be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
const { coords } = res || {};
```

and

```
const { points } = res;
```

is the `|| {}` part. It makes makes the entire right side of the expression to equal `{}` if res is *falsy* therefore doing `{coords} = {}` is allowed.

Comment: @goldman OMG. I feel so dumb, it was starting at me right in the face and I could not see it. Thank you soooo much!